# Mongodb grouping array of child

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Good day! I am studying mongodb and I find it difficult to group a child array. I want to group the parameters with same id.

Is it possible in mongodb to group array of child?

Initial array of objects.

```
"attributes": [
    {
        "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6852",
        "parameters": {
            "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6853",
            "parameter": {
                "_id": "5f35539e83477525987a684e",
                "parameter": "HOMEROOM"
            },
            "percentage_allocation": 20
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6852",
        "parameters": {
            "_id": "5f35578d786afe026451470c",
            "parameter": {
                "_id": "5f3553a783477525987a684f",
                "parameter": "PERFORMANCE"
            },
            "percentage_allocation": 20
        }
    }
]
```

Desired Results:

```
"attributes": [
    {
        "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6852",
        "parameters": [{
            "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6853",
            "parameter": {
                "_id": "5f35539e83477525987a684e",
                "parameter": "HOMEROOM"
            },
            "percentage_allocation": 20
        },
        {
                "_id": "5f3553a783477525987a684f",
                "parameter": "PERFORMANCE"
            },
            "percentage_allocation": 20
        }]
    }
]
```

Comment: In expected result, don't u have parameter object in second object?

Comment: Don't attach images, you should post codes

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have a problem displaying json object, the thing is, I have an array of object containing an array of child. Like this [array:[child_array]] The problem is I want to group the child_array like array: group{child_array} but I can't find a way to group an object twice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better solution on my nested array of objects. I used populate and it worked as I want the program to be executed. And it is much cleaner code than before.

```
 data = await SubjectDetails.find(query)
        .populate({
            path: 'academic_year'
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'grade_level'
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'subject'
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'attributes.attribute',
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'attributes.parameters.parameter',
        })
        .sort({
            "subject.subject": 1
        })
        .exec()
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `$unwind` to flat the array.
Then `$group` it by `_id` to regroup as you need.
Again `$group` it to add to attributes array.

```
[
  {
    $unwind: "$attributes"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$attributes._id",
      parameters: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$attributes._id",
          parameter: "$attributes.parameter",
          percentage_allocation: "$attributes.percentage_allocation"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      attributes: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dYhK9mGDxLK)

Comment: Wow man you're a genius! It's working. Many thanks! you're a life saver!!